# Surface Go 2 NFC - Reading credit card data

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, nfc, pcsc

For a KYC process, i'm trying to use the Surface Go 2 NFC module to read credit card data (PAN and user name) through a wpf app and win 10 api contracts.

I am using the [Windows 10 API - ProximityDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Networking.Proximity.ProximityDevice?view=winrt-19041)  class which seems to work with the module (eg. DeviceArrived is raised when i get my credit card near the tablet) but i don't know how to send APDU and read the response afterwards.

I see that i have a PublishBinaryMessage method which can be used for NDEF comms like this

```
_device.PublishBinaryMessage("NDEF:WriteTag", msg.ToByteArray().AsBuffer());
```

but is there anything to simply read the response as byte arrays ?

I then tried the [Win 10 API - SmartCardReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.smartcards?view=winrt-19041) class, but the NFC module doesn't come up that way, i only get a "Microsoft IFD 0" which doesn't respond when i tried to tap my card...

I also tried the old PC/SC way via this wrapper https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp but the reader doesn't come up...

Could this be a NFC compatibility issue ? How could i check ?

Comment: Smart Card is normally locked with an encryption key and must be unlocked before using.  You can unlock the smart card automatically using a File Explorer which automatically calls the smart card driver to unlock the card.  Snart cards have 8/16/32/64 bit address/data modes and you must use the app must work with the mode the card is using.  Also the encryption mode must also be supported by the application.  i would first try reading the card with a file explorer.  If the file explorer doesn't work then you probably didn't install the correct driver for the card.

Comment: Nothing pops up in the explorer when i put my card near the nfc module. I'll be asking NXP directly. Thanks

Comment: Do you see the card listed in the File Explorer?  Check Device Manager.  The card should show up in the Device Manager and should not be yellow.  Right now I suspect you didn't install the driver for the Card.

Comment: @jdweng no i have not installed any specific driver. I asked NXP if there was one dedicated to smart cards, i am still waiting for an answer. There is something else, the embedded module is listed as "proximity" device in the device manager and not as a smart card reader.

Comment: It may be the smart card with the wrong driver installed so it has a different name.  Usually the fix is to delete the device and driver in device manager.  Then reboot the computer.  The Plug and Play should recognize the card and ask for the driver location.  Sometimes you can just update the driver and browse for correct driver.  I would check the vendor website to see if you can find the driver.

Comment: See following :https://drivers.softpedia.com/get/CARD-READERS/Others/NXP-ProximityBased-SmartCard-Reader-Driver-1-0-4-42-for-Windows-10-64-bit.shtml

Comment: Well thanks for your time @jdweng, it did not work but a surface firmware update did the trick, i can now see "NXP' ProximityBased SmartCard Reader" in the device manager. Thanks again !

Comment: Then you needed to do both.  Add driver and do Firmware update. The driver was needed.  When developing the c# software ware I recommend unlocking in windows and then get your c# Read and write software working.  Make sure you are using a compatible address/data mode size in c#.  Unlocking card in c# you must know the address/data size.  Once you get the Read and Write working then you can go back and unlock card with c# code.

Comment: Well, here's where i'm at now : the reader is available but when i set up my event handler to detect the nfc device arrival, none is ever triggered.

About what you said related to unlocking the card in windows explorer, it is not applicable with a credit card. It works well with my omnikey reader without this particular step.

Comment: It depends on the type of device the driver uses.  Normally when I use a card the driver installs the device as a File System.  In you case it is setup as an I/O device.  The API will do the unlocking.  The receive events need to be registered using : proximityDevice.DeviceArrived += ProximityDeviceArrived;proximityDevice.DeviceDeparted += ProximityDeviceDeparted;  The card is a slave and you application is a client.  So you probably have to send a command and then get the response.

Comment: Well, a little sumup, i had contact with MS tech support and Surface Go 2 Enterprise doesn't provide support for NFC payment. While payment is not what i want to achieve, i think it explains why the SmartCardReader API isn't triggered with a credit card. It simply won't work with the PCSC lib i want to use and i won't reimplement all of it with ProximityDevice API

Comment: Read your original link : https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp?force_isolation=true#pcsc-wrapper-classes-for-net

Comment: Yes, that i what i used to build my sample which work the third-party reader. But it connects to the reader via SmardCard API and not Proximity underneath

Comment: There is a windows link on the page that goes to these methods : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/smart-card-and-reader-access-functions

Comment: https://www.idwholesaler.com/learning-center/whats-the-difference-between-a-prox-card-and-a-smart-card/?force_isolation=true